# reverse an observable array in angularfire2 angular 6

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am using a Observable array for real time data coming. The data comes in ascending order, but I need it to display in reverse order. Examples on internet are before angular 5 and the syntax no longer works. Please advise

html

```
  <tr *ngFor="let card of cards  | async;let last = last ">
              <td> <img [src]="card.frontImageUrl" width=200 height="100"></td>
</td>


refreshCards(){
    this.cards = this.dataSvc.fetchCards().pipe(
      map((cards: any) => cards.map(cardObj => new Card(cardObj.key, cardObj._frontImageUrl, cardObj._backImageUrl, cardObj._status, cardObj._date, cardObj._userId, cardObj._message)))
    );
  }
```

call to firedb

```
fetchCards(){
    this.cardList = this.db.list<Card>('adminCardQueue', ref => ref.orderByChild('_date').limitToLast(50))

    return this.cardList.snapshotChanges().pipe(
       map(changes => 
        changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()}))
       )
      ) ;
  }
```

Comment: Hey, have you tried to reverse the array at *ngFor using **.slice().reverse()**? Ex: let card of (posts | async)?.slice().reverse()

Comment: awesome this worked. u was not using .slice() adding that worked

Comment: Let me put it in a answer to be visible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reverse the array at *ngFor using .slice().reverse()

```
<tr *ngFor="let card of (cards | async)?.slice().reverse();let last = last ">
```

The **.slice()** creates a copy of the array and the **.reverse()** does the reverse action on your array.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ---

```
*ngFor="let item of items.slice().reverse()"
```

Comment: Your answer is useful without `async pipe`. If someone is using `async pipe`  in `ngFor` that possibly means that he has an `Observable<Array>` in his component. And If that's the case. Then with your answer, an error will occur by saying `slice does not exists on type 'Observable<Array>'`. So in that case you have to use the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reversing an Observable or an Array inside template is possible but **not recommended at all**. Do not bring any sort of `JavaScript function's logic` inside html template.

**WHY**

**1-** It will work in `development` but in `production` it will not reverse the array.

**2-** It is the incorrect use of Angular Framework. As you are `mutating` an array inside of `change detection cycle`.

**Refrence** https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34131

**Solution**
You should reverse your array inside `Ts`.

```
refreshCards(){
    this.cards = this.dataSvc.fetchCards().pipe(
      map((cards: any) => cards.map(cardObj => new Card(cardObj.key, cardObj._frontImageUrl, cardObj._backImageUrl,
cardObj._status, cardObj._date, cardObj._userId, cardObj._message).slice().reverse())
    );
  }
```

**ZOOMED `new Card()`**

```
new Card(cardObj.key, cardObj._frontImageUrl, cardObj._backImageUrl,
    cardObj._status, cardObj._date, cardObj._userId, cardObj._message).slice().reverse()
```